# Installation error with pjsua application in Genymotion

Tags: android, pjsip

Pjsua sip calling application successfull run on devices,but it crash on genymotion.

following is the crash log.

```
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Couldn't load pjsua2 from
> loader
> dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[dexPath=/data/app/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2.apk,libraryPath=/data/app-lib/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2]:
> findLibrary returned null.

dlopen("/data/app-lib/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2/libpjsua2.so") failed: Cannot load library: load_library(linker.cpp:766): not a valid ELF executable: /data/app-lib/org.pjsip.pjsua2.app-2/libpjsua2.so
```

It also crash on Samasung Galaxy S3.